# Transformation an image file in tcp/ip

Tags: c#, arrays, image, byte, tcp

I convert image file into a byte array and packetize it to 14-byte packets and  send it via SerialPortEventHandler. on the other hand, in reciever part I lost some packets and when I generate recieved byte array in a new image file, the rest of the image, after the lost packet, shifted incorrectly, I have replaced lost packets with zero. while this works with text file perfectly. This is my code in client and server side:

```
    client 

      _file = ofile.ConvertFileToByte(txtFileName.Text);
      for (int k = 0; k < Configuration.PacketNumberInFrame; k++)
                        {

                            ((BackgroundWorker)sender).ReportProgress((j * Configuration.PacketNumberInFrame + i) * 100 / Configuration.FileCount);

                            if (i + _numberOfByte <= Configuration.FileCount)
                                _packet = _file.SubArray(i, _numberOfByte);
    }
    //send packet
    ...

    Server


     try
                {

                    while (true)
                    {
                        size = port.BytesToRead;

                        if (size >= 18)
                            break;

                    }
                    byte[] packet = new byte[size];
                    var str2 = port.Read(packet, 0, size);

                    if (System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(packet).Contains(Configuration.EndKeyByte) && !endFlag)
                        EndRecieving();
                    else
                        Extract(packet);
                }
                catch
                    (Exception ex)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }

            }

    public Extract(packet)
    {
     Recieve_Data.Add( packet);
    }

    public EndRecieving()
    {
    for(int i=0;i<  arrayResult.AddRange(packetData);i++)
    {
      arrayResult.AddRange(packetData);
    }
     string filePath = Configuration.LogFilePath + "\\CreatedFile-" + "."filePrefix.ToLower();
  var stream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Create,
                FileAccess.ReadWrite);

            FileData oFile = new FileData();

            stream.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
            stream.Close();

    }
```

Comment: can you provide the important pieces of your code?

Comment: @TobiasTheel  I have edited my question with with my code in client and server side.